# Uploads not working properly NGINX + Passenger + Carrierwave + Carrierwave_backgrounder

Tags: nginx, passenger, carrierwave

I have a Rails 4.0.0 app setup with a model called `episode` which mounts a carrierwave uploader called `file_uploader` to upload mp3s. I got my app setup using carrierwave_backgrounder and resque to background the processing of the uploaded files which are saved to an sftp server using the carrierwave-ftp gem. On my local machine it works great. Also on my vps (CentOS 6) it works great when I just start up the app using `rails s` or even `rails s -e production`. However when I switch to nginx + passenger, it no longer works as expected.

The files are uploaded to the `/public/uploads/tmp` dir where they are supposed be stored temporarily, but they never get moved into the upload dir that I have specified and none of the other post-processing stuff gets done, like setting content type, removing cache dirs, setting file size and length, etc.

So, yesterday, I switched from using the carrierwave_backgrounder command `save_in_background` to `process_in_background` and now it works fine for files stored locally, however, when I switch to sftp storage using the carrierwave-ftp gem, the files get processed, i.e., they are transferred to my sftp server and the path is stored in my model, but then the job hangs in the Resque queue.

The relevant code that is not getting executed is:

```
process :set_content_type
process :save_content_type_duration_and_size_in_model
```

Does anyone have any idea why this would work fine using development mode and even production mode but not using nginx + passenger?

Here's all the relevant code below:

episode.rb:

```
class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
    # require 'mp3info'

    mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
    process_in_background :file
    belongs_to :podcast

  validates :name, :podcast, :file, presence: true

  default_scope { order("created_at DESC") }

  scope :most_recent, ->(max = 5) { limit(max) }
end
```

file_uploader.rb:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

  storage :sftp

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "#{model.podcast.name.to_s.downcase.parameterize}"
  end

  before :store, :remember_cache_id
  after :store, :delete_tmp_dir

  # This is the relevant code that is not getting executed
  process :set_content_type
  process :save_content_type_duration_and_size_in_model

  def save_content_type_duration_and_size_in_model
    model.content_type = file.content_type if file.content_type
    model.file_size = file.size
    Mp3Info.open(model.file.current_path) do |media|
      model.duration = media.length
    end
  end

  # store! nil's the cache_id after it finishes so we need to remember it for deletion
  def remember_cache_id(new_file)
    @cache_id_was = cache_id
  end

  def delete_tmp_dir(new_file)
    # make sure we don't delete other things accidentally by checking the name pattern
    if @cache_id_was.present? && @cache_id_was =~ /\A[\d]{8}\-[\d]{4}\-[\d]+\-[\d]{4}\z/
      FileUtils.rm_rf(File.join(root, cache_dir, @cache_id_was))
    end
  end
end
```

config/initializers/carrierwave_backgrounder.rb:

```
CarrierWave::Backgrounder.configure do |c|
  c.backend :resque, queue: :carrierwave
end
```

config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.sftp_host = "ftphost.com"
  config.sftp_user = "ftp_user"
  config.sftp_folder = "ftp_password"
  config.sftp_url = "http://url.com"
  config.sftp_options = {
    :password => "ftp_password",
    :port     => 22
  }
end
```

I'm starting Resque with the command: `QUEUE=* bundle exec rake environment resque:work &`

If you need more info, just ask. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Well, oddly enough as is often the case, it is now magically working. Not sure what did the trick, so I'm afraid this won't be of any help to anyone else who stumbles on this page.

Comment: Did you try store_in_background instead of process_in_background?

Comment: @trueinViso, yes that's what I was using first

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue. My process blocks run in development (rails s) but not under apache2/passenger. It's not pretty, but the way i solved it was to move my process code into the after :cache callback. The process blocks are called between the after and before cache callbacks so this seemed reasonable to me.

Here's the super weird part: I don't mean to call the functions, i mean to copy the code out of your process blocks (or functions) and paste directly into your after_cache callback.

I know i'm doing something wrong to cause this situation but i cannot figure it out. Hope this helps you.

```
version :office_preview
  # comment out the following since it does nothing under Passenger
  #process :office_to_img

end

def office_to_img
 this won't be called under passenger :(
end

after :cache, :after_cache

def after_cache(file)
  #for some reason, calling it here doesn't do anything 
  #office_to_img
  code copied&pasted here from office_to_img
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try it out when I get a chance.